# Sum all numChildren retorned by Firebase in JS

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get the total of the sum of numChildren array returned by Firebase, in my case, it's [1,1,2,3,4]. I need it to be 11, but i don't have any idea of how. I tried with sum and reduce function, but have not result. here below i leave my code and some examples in my console.

```js
const dbRefResenas = firebase.database().ref('Clientes/' + allUserData1.empresa + '/resena/' + 'excelentes/' + dt.getFullYear())
    dbRefResenas.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childData) {
            childData.forEach(function(childDataItem) {
                childDataItem.forEach(function(childDataItems) {
                    console.log(childDataItems.numChildren());
                })
            })
        })
   })
```

[My db refreshed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjxiK.png)

[image: My console]

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting all data in one go, it's actually quite simple:

```
const dbRefResenas = firebase.database().ref('Clientes/' + allUserData1.empresa + '/resena/' + 'excelentes/' + dt.getFullYear())
    dbRefResenas.once("value")
    .then(function(snapshot){
        var sum = 0;
        snapshot.forEach(function(childData) {
            childData.forEach(function(childDataItem) {
                childDataItem.forEach(function(childDataItems) {
                    sum = sum + childDataItems.numChildren();
                })
            })
        })
        console.log(sum);
   })
```

Note that if you do this repeatedly, and don't use the data in `snapshot` in any other way, this is quite a waste of bandwidth. You might want to keep a count of the total number of children in a separate node in the database, and update that upon every database write. While the writes will be more complex this way, reading the count in that case would be a lot simpler/cheaper. See the [`child-children` sample in the functions-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/Node-8/child-count).

Comment: Thank you very much man, you made my day, it's work for me. Thanks again!